# Filling object contours

Tags: contour, opencv, flood-fill, python

I have a binary image with contours which was generated without any pre-built function using [this](https://github.com/captanlevi/Contour-Detection-Pytorch/blob/master/extract_contours.py). And the image is

[image]

Now, I would like to fill these objects based on the contours and the output is

[image]

Now, I have the second image for which I extracted the contours using `cv2.Laplacian` as below

[image]

And the object filling looks as below

[image]

And the code used for filling the contours is

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv

image = cv.imread('test1.png')
im_floodfill = image.copy()
h, w = image.shape[:2]
mask = np.zeros(( h +2, w+ 2), np.uint8)
cv.floodFill(im_floodfill, mask, (0, 0), (255, 255, 255))

cv.imshow('Full Mask', im_floodfill)
cv.waitKey(0)

cv.imwrite('filled_circle_200_big.png', im_floodfill)
```

Now, I don't understand why do I get two different fills with the same piece of code? In the first image it fills correctly but in the second, it just fills the top part of the image which is background,but doesn't go beyond that. Is it because of the way the contours are extracted or Am I missing something here?

Thanks in advance